# Continuous color-scroll on click

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll through 3 different colors by clicking on a li element. (This will only change each individual li element).

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

             $("li").click( function() {
               $("li").css("color", "red", "green", "black");
             });
 });
```

Comment: Can you detail what exactly you tried, what the code returns and how it differs from the desired output?

Comment: When I click a li-element, it changes the color of all li-elements to red. What I want is to by clicking it once more, change the color to green, and then once more to black.

Comment: Please add corresponding html code to make a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold color values and a data attribute which keeping the position of the color in the array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let colors = ["red", "green", "black"];
  $('li').click(function() {
    // cache the element reference
    let $this = $(this);
    // get count value if not found then set to 0
    let c = $this.data('count') || 0;

    // set color based on count value
    $this.css("color", colors[c]);

    // update count value
    $this.data('count', ++c % colors.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
  <li>sss</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can I change each individual li-element instead of all li-elements?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to change the list-style-type on click instead of color? (only to states, circle and disc)

Comment: @Martin list style is for entire ul

Comment: Only for each individual li-element. (So if I press a li-element, it changes the bullet from circle to disc).

Comment: @Martin : yes you can

Comment: @Martin :  check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: Will try figuring it out! Thank you.